# Is there possible to using “if-then-else” statement in keyboard-binding gtk.css file?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gtk, eclipse, ide

Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747264/is-it-possible-to-use-arrow-keys-alone-to-expand-tree-node-in-package-explorer-i/ I've found good idea to change behavior of treeview in eclipse. I'd like to improve it, but I'm don't know how to do, because i cant found example of using if-then-else statement in gtk.css configuration file.

I've found the couple of methods "test-collapse-row" and "test-expand-row" in ref below https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-select-cursor-row to test current line on expandable it or not. I've tried to find an example with condition for css key bindings but yet not found.

```
@binding-set MyTreeViewBinding
{
   bind "Left"     { "select-cursor-parent" ()
                  "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) };
   /* I've try code below instead code above - isn't work
   bind "Left"     { if ("test-expand-row" ()) 
                         "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) 
                     else 
                         "select-cursor-parent" () }; */
   bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) };
}

treeview
{
   -gtk-key-bindings: MyTreeViewBinding;
}
```

I need if it node, and it not collapsed collapse it, but if it not node or it already collapsed set up pointer to parent, but don't collapse it.

Comment: Ever found the solution to the problem?

Comment: I found a workaround to do just the same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60376697/1051589